CSP reporting Kaspersky-labs injecting code - what effect will blocking have?
I'm updating the CSP for one of our sites and monitoring traffic from our users using report only mode.  I've noticed that Kaspersky labs is injecting code in our application pages.  I am wondering what the effect is going to be when I block this...
Has anyone else run into this issue before?
connect-src gc.kis.v2.scr.kaspersky-labs.com        
script-src-elem gc.kis.v2.scr.kaspersky-labs.com
style-src-elem  gc.kis.v2.scr.kaspersky-labs.com

Rod

I also get these in reports and they are blocked. Kaspersky, zscaler, and other security products may inject like this. It also happens with malware and browser extensions. Typically with only a fraction of users impacted. If blocking causes any issues to your site Kaspersky is rewriting in a very intrusive way and should learn to rewrite the CSP at the same time.

Thanks.  I think I may go ahead and block.  I really dislike products that inject themselves into our web app....
